# Error: 'FileId' field header not found. Parameter name: name

Tags: c#, lumenworks

I am new to CsvHelper, my apologies if I have missed something in the documentation.

I have a CSV file with 200 off columns. Typically there would be close to 65000 rows. Importing these rows into a SQL Database Table was fine, until I added a new field in the SQL Database Table called "FileId" - which does not exist in the CSV File. I wish to Inject this field and the relevant value.

How do I do this please?

Please see code below I am using:

```
const string fileToWorkWith = @"C:\Data\Fidessa ETP Files\Import\2019\myCsvFile.csv";
Output.WriteLn($"Working with file {fileToWorkWith}.");

const string databaseConnectionString = "Server=MyServer;Database=DB;User Id=sa; Password = xyz;";

Output.WriteLn($"Checking if working file exists.");

if (new System.IO.FileInfo(fileToWorkWith).Exists == false)
{
    Output.WriteLn("Working file does not exist.", Output.WriteTypes.Error);
    return;
}

Output.WriteLn("Reading file.");
using (var reader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(fileToWorkWith), true, char.Parse(",") ))
{
    reader.Columns = new List<LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv.Column>
    {
        new LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv.Column { Name = "FileId", Type = typeof(int), DefaultValue = "1" },
    };
    reader.UseColumnDefaults = true;

    Output.WriteLn("Checking fields in file exist in the Database.");
    foreach (var fieldName in reader.GetFieldHeaders())
    {

        if (Fields.IsValid(fieldName.Replace(" ","_")) == false)
        {
            Output.WriteLn($"A new field named {fieldName} has been found in the file that does not exist in the database.", Output.WriteTypes.Error);
            return;
        }
    }

    using (var sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(databaseConnectionString))
    {
        sbc.DestinationTableName = "FidessaETP.tableARC_EventsOrderAndFlow_ImportTest";
        sbc.BatchSize = 1000;

        Output.WriteLn("Mapping available Csv Fields to DB Fields");
        foreach (var field in reader.GetFieldHeaders().ToArray())
        {
            sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(field, field.Replace(" ", "_"));
        }

        sbc.WriteToServer(reader);
    }    
}
```

The Error Details

Message:
'FileId' field header not found. Parameter name: name

Source:
LumenWorks.Framework.IO

Stack Trace:

> System.ArgumentException: 'FileId' field header not found. Parameter
>   name: name at
>   LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv.CsvReader.System.Data.IDataRecord.GetOrdinal(String
>   name) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerCommon(Int32
>   columnCount) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32
>   columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader) at
>   Haitong.Test.CsvImporter.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Development\Workspaces\UK OPS Data Warehouse\UK OPS Data
>   Warehouse\Haitong.Test.CsvImporter\Program.cs:line 86

Comment: When you're debugging, at what line (or area of the code) does the error occur?

Comment: Missed the StackTrace at the bottom, apologies.

Comment: Hi @JohnPete22, it throws at line "sbc.WriteToServer(reader);"

Comment: Simple question: why not just update the CSV to add a new column so it matches the datatable you're writing to?  It seems the schema is obviously the issue.  The table you're writing to is different than the CSV file.  Make them the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to solve the problem by loading the CSV data into a DataTable, adding a FileId column with a default value to the table, and passing the DataTable into the SqlBulkCopy.  It doesn't look like your current solution loads the whole file into memory, so you should monitor memory usage if you try this approach.  You might be able to get your current solution to work if you dig through the documentation of the Columns property of the CsvReader.  It looks like it does not behave the way you are trying to use it.

Here is an example of you you might load the file using a DataTable:

```
        DataTable csvTable = new DataTable();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, true))
            {
                csvTable.Load(csv);
            }
        }

        DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn("FileId", typeof(System.Int32));
        newColumn.DefaultValue = 1;
        csvTable.Columns.Add(newColumn);

        using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
        {
            sbc.WriteToServer(csvTable);
        }
```